Monaco editor cannot be highlighted in Vue3
I am using Vue 3 (3.5.13) + Vite (5.4.11) with "monaco-editor": "^0.52.2" (I also tried 0.30.1), but syntax highlighting is not working. However, it works fine in Vue 2 (2.6.12) + Webpack (4.46.0).
Attempt 1: I imported _.contribution.js from node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages and called the registerLanguage method, and syntax highlighting worked. But I’m unsure how to enable syntax highlighting for JSON, as there is no JSON file in that directory.
Attempt 2: I configured window.MonacoEnvironment, but the getWorker function is not being executed.
How can I configure the language so that the correct syntax highlighting is applied?
<template>
  <div id="monaco-editor-box" ref="monacoEditorBox" :style="{ height: props.height }">
    <div class="editor-wrapper">
      <div id="monaco-editor" ref="monacoEditor" :style="{ ...editorStyle, height: props.height || '500px' }"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, watch, ref, nextTick } from 'vue'
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api'
// import * as EditorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker'
// import * as jsonWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker'
// import * as cssWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker?worker'
// import * as htmlWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker?worker'
// import * as tsWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker?worker'

const emit = defineEmits(['onCodeChange'])
const props = defineProps({
  types: {
    type: String,
    default: 'json'
  },
  codes: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  height: {
    type: String,
    default: '100%'
  }
})

const monacoEditor = ref()
const monacoEditorBox = ref()
let editor = null
const fullScreenStyle = ref(false)
const editorStyle = ref({ width: '100%' })

let resizeObserver

onMounted(() => {
  initEditor()
})
const initEditor = () => {
  window.MonacoEnvironment = {
    getWorker: (workerId, label) => {
      if (label === 'json') {
        return new Worker(new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker', import.meta.url))
      }
      return new Worker(new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
  // self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  //   getWorker(_, label) {
  //     if (label === 'json') {
  //       // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  //       return new jsonWorker()
  //     }
  //     if (label === 'css' || label === 'scss' || label === 'less') {
  //       // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  //       return new cssWorker()
  //     }
  //     if (label === 'html' || label === 'handlebars' || label === 'razor') {
  //       // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  //       return new htmlWorker()
  //     }
  //     if (label === 'typescript' || label === 'javascript') {
  //       // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  //       return new tsWorker()
  //     }
  //     // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  //     return new EditorWorker()
  //   }
  // }
  editor = monaco.editor.create(monacoEditor.value, {
    value: props.types === 'json' ? formatJson(JSON.stringify(props.codes)) : props.codes,
    language: props.types,
    theme: 'vs-dark',
    automaticLayout: true
  })
  editor.onDidChangeModelContent(() => {
    emit('onCodeChange', editor.getValue())
  })
}
function formatJson(code) {
  try {
    const parsedJson = JSON.parse(code.replace(/'/g, '"'))
    const prettyJson = JSON.stringify(parsedJson, null, 2)
    return prettyJson
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#monaco-editor {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

.editor-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#monaco-editor-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
</style>


<template>
  <div class="format-JSON" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <codeEditor types="json" :codes="codes" @onCodeChange="onCodeChange" />
    <br />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import codeEditor from '@/components/codeEditor.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const codes = ref('')
const onCodeChange = (val) => {
  console.log(val, 'val')
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">
</style>


